# External JQuery doesn't work for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamically created calendar which has hidden div's (css) for events.  I have a JQuery function that should show the div when the event is hovered over, but it doesn't seem to want to work.  I have read everything I could find on this site about the issue, but no luck.

The dynamic content:

```
$calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;">';
        /* add in the day number */
        $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';

        $event_day = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$list_day));
                        foreach($events as $event) {
                            if ($event[ArrDate] == $event_day) {
                                $cntry = $event[CountryID];
                                $calendar.= '</br></br><div class="event" style="background-color:#1' .stringToColorCode($cntry). '">'.$event[CaptainLast]."<div class='teampopup'><table><tbody><tr><u>Team Info:</u></tr></br><tr>Captain: " . $event[CaptainFirst]. " " . $event[CaptainLast] . "</tr></br><tr>Country: " . $event[CountryID]. "</tr></br><tr>Dates: " . date("n/j",strtotime($event[ArrDate])). " - ". date("n/j",strtotime($event[DepDate])). ", " . date("Y",strtotime($event[ArrDate])). "</tr></br><tr>Type: " . $event[Type]. "</tr></tbody></table></div></div>";
                            }
                        }
$calendar.= '</div></td>';
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var moveLeft = -200;
   var moveDown = -50;
   $('#content').on("mouseenter", ".event", function() {
      $(this).find('.teampopup').show();
   }) .on("mouseleave", ".event", function() {
      $(this).find('.teampopup').hide();
   });
});
```

Extra info:  "content" is the container in which the dynamically created content is loaded, and the call to my javascript file is below all my other script tags, just above the closing body tag.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to see logs (console.log() function) if mouseenter event is working or not?

Comment: The strangest thing... it now suddenly appears to be working this morning without any changes.

Comment: sometimes due to browser caching. i suggest to use CTLR + F5, when refreshing as well as clearing ng browser's cache.